# ReplaceAll Method

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

I want to replace "\" with this "/" in my string. 
I am using method replaceAll for this. But it is giving me error.

```
String filePath = "D:\pbx_u01\apache-tomcat-6.0.32\bin\uploadFiles\win.jpg";
String my_new_str = filePath.replaceAll("\\", "//");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you absolutely want to use regex for this, use:

```
String filePath   = "D:\\pbx_u01\\apache-tomcat-6.0.32\\bin\\uploadFiles\\win.jpg";
String my_new_str = filePath.replaceAll("\\\\", "/");
```

Output of `my_new_str` would be:

```
D:/pbx_u01/apache-tomcat-6.0.32/bin/uploadFiles/win.jpg
```

Just be sure to notice the *double* backslashes `\\` in the source `String` (you used *single* ones `\` in your question.)


But [Mena](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2353911/mena) showed in his answer a much simpler, more readable way to achive the same. (Just adopt the slashes and backslashes)

Answer (score 2):

Just use `replace`.

The method `replaceAll` takes a regular expression and yours would be malformed.

```
String filePath = "D:/pbx_u01/apache-tomcat-6.0.32/bin/uploadFiles/win.jpg";
System.out.println(filePath.replace("/", "\\"));
```

**Output**

```
D:\pbx_u01\apache-tomcat-6.0.32\bin\uploadFiles\win.jpg
```

Comment: sorry i have posted the opposite of the question. i have not edited it. please tell me the solution

Comment: @FahadMurtaza This is the solution. If the replace is backwards, I'm sure you can figure out how to switch which character is replaced.

Answer (score 0):

You are **unable** because character **'//'** should be typed  only single **'/'**.

```
String filePath = "D:\\pbx_u01\\apache-tomcat-6.0.32\\bin\\uploadFiles\\win.jpg"
String my_new_str = filePath.replaceAll("\\", "/");
```

Above may be fail during execution giving you a **PatternSyntaxException**, because the first String is a regular expression so you use this,

```
String filePath = "D:\\pbx_u01\\apache-tomcat-6.0.32\\bin\\uploadFiles\\win.jpg"
String my_new_str = filePath.replaceAll("\\\\", "/");
```

#### Check this <kbd>**[Demo ideOne](http://ideone.com/howV64)**</kbd>

Comment: Hint: Your `\\\` is a illegal escape sequence

Comment: @ifLoop Thank you for pointing me i update as your suggestion.